# php mvc Роутер, вернуть 404 ошибку или поймать ошибку Fatal error

Tags: php, mvc, исключения

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести 404 ошибку. Мой роутер выглядит так. Сейчас роутер возвращает фатальную ошибку, если не находит путь. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method IndexController::actionIndexfindex() in...

```
class Router {

private $routes;

public function __construct()
{
    $routesPath = ROOT.'/config/routes.php';
    $this->routes = include($routesPath);
}

// Получаем строку запроса
private function getURI()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
    }

}



public function run()
{

    // Получить строку запроса
    $uri = $this->getURI();

    // Проверить такого наличия запроса в routes.php
    foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {
        // Если есть совпадения определить какой контроллер и action обрабатывают запрос
        if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {

            // Получаем внутренний путь из внешнего согласно правилу
            $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);

            // Определяем контроллер, action, параметры
            $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

            $controllerName = array_shift($segments).'Controller';
            $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

            $actionName = 'action'.ucfirst((array_shift($segments)));

            $parameters = $segments;

            // Подключить файл класса контроллера
            $controllerFile = ROOT.'/controllers/'.$controllerName.'.php';
            if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                include_once($controllerFile);
            }

            // Создать объект, вызвать метод (т.е. action)
            $controllerObject = new $controllerName;

            $result = $controllerObject->$actionName($parameters);

            if ($result !== NULL) {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: вам не кажется, что стоит проверять наличие метода `$actionName` у объекта `$controllerObject`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, я этого не знал! Получилось отловить, сейчас буду делать обработку. Еще раз благодарю за направление!

Comment: сделал это встроенной функцией php method_exists($controllerName,$actionName)

Comment: Так же стоит проверять на `is_callable()`

Comment: спасибо, посмотрел.